# If we have a set, is it possible for this set to be a partition of itself with a single equivalence class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

It is commonly known that if we have a binary equivalence relation $R$ defined on some set $W$ its equivalence classes form a partition of $W$. So, let $W = \{5, \sqrt{25}, \frac{10}{2} \}$ be a set, in which all of its elements are equal. What kind of partition of $W$ will be defined by the equivalence relation $= \subseteq W \times W$? Can we say that $W$ is a partition of itself?

Comment: Yes, see [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Definition): For any non-empty set $X, P = \{  X \}$ is a partition of $X$, called the **trivial partition**.

Comment: If a set $W$ has "all the elements equal", then either it has exactly one element or it has none. If the former, then $\{W\}$ is the only partition. If the latter, then $\emptyset$ is the only partition.

Comment: Instead of "all of its elements equal", perhaps you meant "all of its elements equivalent"?

Comment: The elements of a partition of $X$ are some subsets of $X$, not (in general) elements of $X$. In your example, $W=\{5\}$ and $\{W\}$ (not $W$) is the only partition of $W$. The same thing happens for any other one-element set. The only set that is a partition of itself is the empty set.